# About the theorem that links limits of sequences and limits of functions, and the arbitrary delta.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

First things first, I apologize if at any point I spell any formulas incorrectly or if at any point I name something wrongly (I am taking the class in another language and I am translating everything at the best of my abilities).
In my mathematics class, I am reading about the following theorem:
The following expressions are the same and are equivalent:

- ${\forall x_n \to x_0, x_n \in A-\{x_0\} \forall n \in N \implies f(x_n)}$
- ${\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : |f(x)-l| < \epsilon \forall x \in A : 0 < |x-x_0|<\delta}$

Those theorems on their own seems logic, and I can understand intuitively why they are true. My doubt arises when I try to prove one implies the other. More specifically, when the first implies the second.
Let's prove the first implies the second by proving it would be absurd for the second not to work, assuming the first works.

The second formula not working would mean that ${\exists \epsilon_0 : \forall \delta > 0 \exists x \in A : 0 < |x-x_0|<\delta, |f(x)-l|\geq\epsilon_0}$.

Let x a sequence ${x_n \in A-\{x_0\}}$, by proving it approaches ${x_0}$ as n approaches positive infinity and assuming the first expression is true, then ${f(x_n)\to l}$.

The explanation in my textbook goes as follows:
Let ${\delta}$ be ${\frac{1}{n}}$, since ${0<|x_n-x_0|<\frac{1}{n}}$ then ${x_0 - \frac{1}{n} < x_n < x_0 + \frac{1}{n}}$, but since ${\frac{1}{n}} \to 0$, then it is obvious that $x_n \to x_0$ the first implying the second is now proven.

Here is my question: Why do I have to assume ${\delta = \frac{1}{n}}$ since I am assuming that delta is any positive and non-zero value? Wouldn't it limit ${\delta}$ to be only rational numbers lower or equal than 1? Since ${\epsilon}$ and ${delta}$ depend on one another, and I am setting ${\delta}$ to be an arbitrary value, doesn't that mean that I am also restricting ${\epsilon}$ to assume certain values while it still needs to be any positive and non-zero value?

Comment: When we took negation of the second formula, we now known that for some $\epsilon_0$ *any* $\delta > 0$ will work - in particular, $1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots$ will work. We are guaranteed that other $\delta$ will also work, but we don't need it.

Comment: I apologize for asking further. How are we guaranteed that each and every ${\delta}$ will work the same way? Are we using ${\frac{1}{n}}$ just because it will allow the ${x_n}$ to be "squeezed" into ${x_0}$? Since it should work for any delta, let's assume ${\delta}$ is now equal to some random number that is not infinitely close to zero (say, ${\delta=7}$). Since we are now unable to "squeeze" ${x_n}$ into ${x_0}$ with a value next to zero, how would we complete the proof?

Comment: Simple example: we know that for any $n$ there is prime $p > n$. We want to show that there is prime greater than $100$. As we have statement that works for any $n$, substitute $n = 100$ and get what we need. If we substitute $n = 50$, this reasoning wouldn't work, but we don't need it to work for any $n$. Similarly, in your case we don't need the proof to work with any choice of $\delta$, it needs to work for at least some.

Comment: I apologize once more, but I don't seem to understand your example, especially because there are real numbers I cannot represent with the notation ${\frac{1}{n}}$ while the notation says "For every real number" and not "For every real number in that set". Please explain this further. I also made an example for ${\delta = 7}$ which you cannot obtain for every ${n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in the form of ${\frac{1}{n}}$ . Also, please reply to this question as an answer rather than a comment, so that I can mark your answer and the question's answer once we sort this thing out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we have already fixed $\epsilon_0$, and now we know that $\forall \delta \exists x \in A: 0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \wedge |f(x) - l| > \epsilon_0$. This part we already have (from negation of 2nd statement), we can use it and we don't have to prove it.

Now, there is general schema: if it's true that $\forall \delta P(\delta)$, then for arbitrary value $t$ we have $P(t)$. Taking $P(\delta) := \exists x \in A: 0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \wedge |f(x) - l| > \epsilon_0$ and $t = \frac{1}{n}$ we get $\exists x \in A: 0 < |x - x_0| < \frac{1}{n} \wedge |f(x) - l| > \epsilon_0$. Denoting this $x$ as $x_n$, we get our sequence (actually, here is some small set-theoretical problem, but it's not important for now).

Of course, we also have save $P(7)$, but this is not important. Saying that something is true "for all real numbers" *implies* it's also true "for all real number in that set" (whatever set we choose). It doesn't work in the other direction, but we don't need it in the other direction. We don't *check* if $P(7)$ is true, we *use* that $P(1)$, $P(1/2)$, $\ldots$ is true.